# ALSA: asound.conf file read but not used with arecord

Tags: configuration, default, alsa

I'm using ALSA to configure a mic, but after some hours of search on stackoverflow/alsa doc/other sources, I don't understand how arecord work...

I'm trying to set a default record

> Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Fréquence 48000 Hz, Stéréo

The equivalent `arecord` CLI command is (in my case) :

`arecord /tmp/test.wav -f dat -D sysdefault:CARD=1`

I try to do that with /etc/asound.conf

I write this :

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  playback.pcm {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "hw:1,0"
  }
  capture.pcm "multi"
}

pcm.multi {
  type plug
  slave.pcm "multiapps"
}

pcm.multiapps {
  type dsnoop
  ipc_key 666666
  slave {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
    format "S16_LE"
    rate 48000
  }
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
}
```

But when I try a simple :

`arecord /tmp/test.wav` or `arecord /tmp/test.wav -D default`

It fails with

> Capture WAVE '/tmp/test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Fréquence 8000 Hz, Mono
>   arecord: set_params:1299: Ce format d'échantillonage n'est pas
>   disponible Available formats:
>   - S16_LE

Just to test, I try with

`arecord /tmp/test.wav -D multi`

I have a half success, it works but with bad configuration

> Capture WAVE '/tmp/test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Fréquence 8000 Hz, Mono

Can someone explain to me what I missed ? :|

Thanks !

**-- EDIT --**

I realize that /etc/asound.conf is overlapped by ~/.asound.

So, I copied the first in the second.

No more fatal on default, but always in 8k/8bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting entries like `format` and `rate` into a slave definition restricts the possible configurations that an application can choose.

Most applications ask the device what configurations it actually supports. However, `aplay`/`arecord` do not; they always try to use the configuration you have set with parameters (or their silly defaults).

Comment: So, arecord that comes with Alsa does not use Alsa configuration file. Hmpf. Thanks :'(

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is wrong:

You *need* to put `format` and `rate` entries in a slave definition if you are not happy with the default configuration (set by the soundcard driver I think) of the **hardware**. (In my case, the default is 16-bit audio, but I want 24-bit because mic signals can be very silent.)

Also in the **application** you need to specify `format` and `rate` if you are not happy with the default. In case of arecord, the default is the telephony standard 8b/8kHz (so not at all silly! - although I prefer 16b/32kHz).

If you have provided the correct ALSA elements that can convert the hardware format to the application format, it will be converted automatically (do `arecord -v` to see the conversions). You use 'plug' in 'pcm.multi' so that is OK.

So you only need now to specify the format you want in your application. So please RTFM, `man aplay` will do:

```
arecord -D multi -c 1 -r 48000 -f S16_LE -v -t wav /tmp/test.wav
```

(About RTFM, I agree that it was hard to find out how it all works :-)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and I think the answer is correct. I would expect that arecord takes over the parameters from asound.conf, however, this is not happening. So even you provide arecord -D option with desired pcm from asound.conf, arecord silently ignore the configuration and uses the defaults.